# Docker build fails with "3.1.101\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5)" error

Tags: docker-compose, build, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that has more lines than these:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-20200211-windowsservercore-ltsc2016 AS BUILDER
WORKDIR c:\src\
COPY . .
RUN nuget restore
RUN dotnet clean ATTAboticsAutomation.sln 
RUN dotnet build ATTAboticsAutomation.sln
...
```

But I am only showing these as the last line (6) above is where the failure happens.
This is how the Dockerfile is being invoked via the powershell file to ensure cache is cleared:

```
docker-compose.exe down
docker-compose.exe build --force-rm --no-cache
...
```

This runs well uptill the build step:

```
Step 1/18 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-20200211-windowsservercore-ltsc2016 AS BUILDER
 ---> 31f0c2ffa55d
Step 2/18 : WORKDIR c:\src\
 ---> Running in e90862540d44
Removing intermediate container e90862540d44
 ---> d45c73302955
Step 3/18 : COPY . .
 ---> ebdc0172b86b
Step 4/18 : RUN nuget restore
 ---> Running in be13a99099a1
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.4.0.56107' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
Removing intermediate container be13a99099a1
 ---> 8598338b6bd0
Step 5/18 : RUN dotnet clean ATTAboticsAutomation.sln
 ---> Running in e24add0bbdc5

Welcome to .NET Core 3.1!
---------------------
SDK Version: 3.1.101

Telemetry
---------
The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. The data is anonymous. It is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.

Read more about .NET Core CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry

----------------
Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core
Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new
Learn about the installed HTTPS developer cert: https://aka.ms/aspnet-core-https
Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs
Write your first app: https://aka.ms/first-net-core-app
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 9/13/2021 8:33:05 PM.
     1>Project "C:\src\ATTAboticsAutomation.sln" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
     1>Done Building Project "C:\src\ATTAboticsAutomation.sln" (Clean target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.98
Removing intermediate container e24add0bbdc5
 ---> 17b0f866d0bd
```

and then fails either by:
**1:**

```
Step 6/18 : RUN dotnet build ATTAboticsAutomation.sln
 ---> Running in f3fb9e6940ce
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
  SpecFlowFeatureFiles: [redacted the list of files]
Stack overflow.
Stack overflow.
Removing intermediate container f3fb9e6940ce
ERROR: Docker build failed!
```

**or 2:**

```
Step 6/18 : RUN dotnet build ATTAboticsAutomation.sln
 ---> Running in f3fb9e6940ce
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
  SpecFlowFeatureFiles: [redacted the list of files]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(135,9): warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset". [C:\src\Automation\Automation.csproj]
Stack overflow.
```

**or 3:**

```
Step 6/18 : RUN dotnet build ATTAboticsAutomation.sln
 ---> Running in f3fb9e6940ce
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
  SpecFlowFeatureFiles: [redacted the list of files]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error MSB6006: "csc.dll" exited with code -1073741819. [C:\src\Automation\Automation.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

This runs fine in CI. It's just the local Docker setup where this consistenly fails.

Searched the web but could not find anything relevant.

The one difference I noted between CI and the above setup is that in CI, in step 4, all the nuget packages are restored and installed. But that's not the case in the local run as shown above. I am wondering if that is the issue. If it is, how would I enforce the nuget packages to reinstall everytime on the local run?

I am not sure if that is the error or if there is something else that is not being properly referenced during the build process.

Comment: You use image `sdk:4.8-20200211` but then build using net core, and why you use `nuget restore` and not `dotnet restore` ?

Comment: Using nuget restore to restore the nuget packages. Does dotnet restore also do that?